# Is there a way to have syntax highlighting or code blocks with Evernote?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, evernote, source-code

How do you take notes on code snippets and or command line sequences in Evernote (Mac or PC)? Is there a way to have code blocks like the 'Code Sample' buttons here:

```
example
```

Any way to have colored syntax highlighting?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This link has exactly what you're looking for

http://www.thoughtasylum.com/blog/2010/6/7/colour-code-notes-in-evernote.html

Comment: This link explains how to add a colored background to notes.  Really doesn't have anything to do with syntax highlighting.

Comment: At the moment, this post is essentially only a link. To make sure the answer remains useful even if the link breaks, please edit it to include the relevant information. (Your answer was discovered in [an effort to repair or remove old link-only answers](http://meta.superuser.com/q/11113/380318).)

Answer (score 0):

Sniptastic is like pastebin which syncs with evernote.

Other than that, closest I cound find was this...
http://chrisshattuck.com/blog/adding-syntax-highlighting-code-snippets-evernote